# notification by mail or any means when dev code appears on web site

Tags: python

it is possible to create notifications when a specific content is required on a website
Example:
Job title: New Figure Eight Reconciliation Job

## of tasks: 0

when he considered
New Figure Eight Reconciliation Job in 0 tasks a notification is created by mail or telegram

website: https://tasks.figure-eight.work/channels/clixsense/tasks?uid=13895622

so far I have only been able to notify an element

```
import requests

Import BeautifulSoup 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Import Time 
import time

import smtplib

while True:
    url = "https://tasks.figure-eight.work/channels/clixsense/tasks?uid=13895622"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    if str(soup).find("New Figure Eight Reconciliation Job") == -1:
        time.sleep(60)
        continue

        msg = 'Assunto: Checagem de site e envio por email'
        fromaddr = 'meu_email@gmail.com'
        toaddrs  = ['AN_EMAIL_ADDRESS','A_SECOND_EMAIL_ADDRESS', 'A_THIRD_EMAIL_ADDRESS']

         server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
         server.starttls()
         Adicionando as credenciais de conta de email
         server.login("YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "YOUR_PASSWORD")


        print('From: ' + fromaddr)
        print('To: ' + str(toaddrs))
        print('Message: ' + msg)


        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
        server.quit()

        break
```